# Unable to deserialize JSON object

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am currently doing a small project using xamarin and abp boilerplate. I'm trying to get the data from my server using Xamarin. I have managed to login and receive the token. When I try to deserializeobject it returns an error returning

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the
>   current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MobileUI.Models.User]' because the
>   type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To
>   fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
>   or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'result', line 1, position 10.

This is the code for GetUserAsync

```
public async Task<List<User>> GetUserAsync(string accessToken)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://serverurl/testrun/api/services/app/user/GetRoles");

    var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);

    return users;
}
```

This is the model code

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}

public partial class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("isStatic")]
    public bool IsStatic { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("permissions")]
    public string[] Permissions { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

I made a breakpoint at `var users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(json);`

Apparently, the error comes from here. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: 
Forgot to add the Response body of the API

```
{
  "result": {
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Admin",
        "displayName": "Admin",
        "description": null,
        "isStatic": true,
        "permissions": [
          "Pages.Users",
          "Pages.Roles",
          "Pages.Tenants"
        ],
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Tenants",
        "displayName": "Tenants",
        "description": "",
        "isStatic": false,
        "permissions": [
          "Pages.Tenants",
          "Pages.Users"
        ],
        "id": 12
      },
      {
        "name": "Landlord",
        "displayName": "Landlord",
        "description": "",
        "isStatic": false,
        "permissions": [
          "Pages.Tenants",
          "Pages.Property",
          "Pages.Payment",
          "Pages.Feedback",
          "Pages.Document",
          "Pages.LandLord",
          "Pages.Users"
        ],
        "id": 14
      },
      {
        "name": "User",
        "displayName": "Users",
        "description": "",
        "isStatic": false,
        "permissions": [
          "Pages.Property",
          "Pages.Payment",
          "Pages.Feedback",
          "Pages.Document"
        ],
        "id": 20
      }
    ]
  },
  "targetUrl": null,
  "success": true,
  "error": null,
  "unAuthorizedRequest": false,
  "__abp": true
}
```

Edit 2: Forgot to add in UserViewModel.cs

```
private List<Item> _users;

//public string AccessToken { get; set; }
public List<Item> Users
{
    get { return _users; }
    set
    {
        _users = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
public ICommand GetUsersCommand
{
    get
    {
        return new Command(async () =>
        {
            var accessToken = Settings.AccessToken;
            Users = await _apiServices.GetUserAsync(accessToken);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: As I see it, only `items` is a list under `"result"`

Answer (score 2):

As per your json, it contains `List` of `items` object and you are deserialising list of `User` object

You should get `result` object from json and under that you will get list of items

```
var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
var items = user.result.Items;
```

And your model should be something like this

```
class User{
    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

class Result{
    [JsonProperty("items")]
    public Item[] Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. After changing the codes with the one you suggested, I got an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'MobileUI.Models.User' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<MobileUI.Models.Item>'
`
Made a 2nd Edit on my question regarding the UserViewModel class

Comment: The error says that you were trying to convert `User` object to `List<Item>` object

Comment: try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this and it worked !
Check this:

```
public class Item
{
  public string name { get; set; }
  public string displayName { get; set; }
  public string description { get; set; }
  public bool isStatic { get; set; }
  public List<string> permissions { get; set; }
  public int id { get; set; }
 }

 public class Result
 {
   public List<Item> items { get; set; }
 }

 public class RootObject
 {
   public Result result { get; set; }
   public object targetUrl { get; set; }
   public bool success { get; set; }
   public object error { get; set; }
   public bool unAuthorizedRequest { get; set; }
   public bool __abp { get; set; }
 }
```

And then I called it like this:

```
var json = "{\"result\":{\"items\":[{\"name\":\"Admin\",\"displayName\":\"Admin\",\"description\":null,\"isStatic\":true,\"permissions\":[\"Pages.Users\",\"Pages.Roles\",\"Pages.Tenants\"],\"id\":1},{\"name\":\"Tenants\",\"displayName\":\"Tenants\",\"description\":\"\",\"isStatic\":false,\"permissions\":[\"Pages.Tenants\",\"Pages.Users\"],\"id\":12},{\"name\":\"Landlord\",\"displayName\":\"Landlord\",\"description\":\"\",\"isStatic\":false,\"permissions\":[\"Pages.Tenants\",\"Pages.Property\",\"Pages.Payment\",\"Pages.Feedback\",\"Pages.Document\",\"Pages.LandLord\",\"Pages.Users\"],\"id\":14},{\"name\":\"User\",\"displayName\":\"Users\",\"description\":\"\",\"isStatic\":false,\"permissions\":[\"Pages.Property\",\"Pages.Payment\",\"Pages.Feedback\",\"Pages.Document\"],\"id\":20}]},\"targetUrl\":null,\"success\":true,\"error\":null,\"unAuthorizedRequest\":false,\"__abp\":true}";

var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but i'm trying to GET data from the API.

Comment: Yes. I understand. I have done the same. Getting the data and then parsing it. All you need is to access user object

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems is the ways of data binding, You can try two way binding or Oneway binding.
Your refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics).